# Celery beat doesn`t run tasks

Tags: python, celery

To be more specific, beat doesn't send tasks to the main worker. It seems to me that problem appeared right after docker installation.

Here`s the code I made just for test:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('myapp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task
def my_task():
    print('Hello, world!')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my-task': {
        'task': 'tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*')
    }
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the Celery worker process
    worker = app.Worker(app=app)
    worker.start()

    # Start the Celery beat process
    beat = app.Beat()
    beat.run()
```

I've tried to run this code. Expected to see "Hello, world!" every minute, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Did you check whether worker.start() blocks or not? It is possible that beat lines are not executed when you expect. The simplest way to check is to put a print line in between worker.start() and beat = app.Beat() . I never start workers and beat like this, so I am not sure what is wrong...